# Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, Find Canonical Jordan form of $A^2$ in correlation to Jordan form of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

No given Information since this question relies on typical Complex matrix.

I know that $J_n(x)= xI+J_n(0)$ but how does it help me? I have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hints: If $J$ is the Jordan form of $A$, then $A$ is similar to $J$. What is $A^2$ similar to? What happens when you square a Jordan block?

Comment: well Since $A=PJP^{-1}$ then $A^2=(P^{-1})^{2}J^2P^2$. $J^2$ is just the square of all the blocks inside. I'm trying to figure out about the square of Jordan block but I understood it depends what is the Eigenvalue ($0$ or not). if the eigenvalue is $0$ then the block might be $0$ block after the square

Comment: That's right, the case of a block with eigenvalue 0 is a bit more complicated. Can you completely solve the problem in the case where all eigenvalues are nonzero?

Comment: If $0$ is not eigenvalue of the Jordan blocks within $J_n$ then $A^2$ is similar to $J_n$ with the same blocks but with square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already determined, it suffices to separately consider the Jordan blocks of $A$. For $x \neq 0$, $J_n(x)^2$ is indeed similar to $J_n(x^2)$.

The question remains: what happens when $x = 0$? We know that the only eigenvalue of $J_n(0)^2$ is zero, but it is not clear what the size of the blocks should be. I claim the following: for all integers $k \geq 1$, $J_{2k}(0)^2$ is similar to $J_{k}(0) \oplus J_k(0)$ and $J_{2k+1}(0)^2$ is similar to $J_{k}(0) \oplus J_{k+1}(0)$, where $\oplus$ denotes a [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum).

One way to prove that this holds is by considering the [Weyr characteristic](https://works.swarthmore.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1027&context=fac-math-stat) (cf. also *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson). In other words, it suffices to note that $\operatorname{rank}((J_{n}(0)^2)^m) = n - 2m$ for all $m < n/2$ and $0$ for $m \geq n/2$. However, I find that a more satisfying approach is to construct a similarity, i.e. to find a matrix $P$ for which $P^{-1}(J_{2k+1}(0)^2)P = J_k(0) \oplus J_{k+1}(0)$.

I will only consider the case of $n = 2\cdot 2 + 1 = 5$, but the general construction is completely analogous. Note that
$$
J_{5}(0)^2 = \pmatrix{0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0}.
$$
Let $e_1,\dots,e_5$ denote the standard basis of $\Bbb R^5$. We note that the vectors $e_1,e_3,e_5$ for a [Jordan chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Jordan_chains).  That is, we have
$$
Je_5 = e_3, \quad Je_3 = e_1, \quad Je_1 = 0.
$$
Similarly, the vectors $e_2,e_4$ form a Jordan chain since we have
$$
Je_4 = e_2, \quad Je_2 = 0.
$$
With that, we can conclude if we take $P$ to be the (permutation) matrix with columns $e_2,e_4,e_1,e_3,e_5$, then we have
$$
P^{-1}J_5(0)^2P = \pmatrix{0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0}
 = J_2(0) \oplus J_3(0).
$$